# Select form input without id in behat

Tags: php, behat, mink

I need to write a custom function to populate an email input field with a unique email address. But the page has dynamically-generated IDs, so I can't just use `$page->find()` to easily grab the elements. How do I grab the input element by its name?

```
public function iFillInUniqueEmail($arg1)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

    $element = $page->find('css', $arg1);

    if (null === $element) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate CSS selector: "%s"', $arg1));
    }

    $date = date('YmdHis');
    $email = "test" . $date . "@test.com";

    $element->setValue($email);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find element by `name` attribute like this:

```
$el = $page->find('css', 'input[name="input_name_goes_here"]');
```